# Pure CSS3 Picture Thumbnail Viewer?

Tags: css, zooming

is the any solution for a pure CSS3 / HTML Thumbnail Zoomer?

2 Solutions would be Ok: A popup Window, or another Div remaining in the Site + showing the current hovered area of the thumbnail picture.

But it has to be without js for eBay.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this

```
#yourDiv:hover {
    transform: scale(5);
}
```

The image might be a tad blurry. But give it a try and see how it works.

Or another option would be to create another div and then add the following css

```
#anotherDiv {
     width: 800px;   /* use whatever width you want, can be px or % */
     height: 500px;  /* use whatever height that works */
     display: none;  /* this will hide it from appearing until the user hovers over the thumbnail #yourDiv */
}

#yourDiv:hover #anotherDiv {
     display: block;  /* this will show it when they hover over thumbnail #yourDiv */
}
```